# form: doesn't send input - submit won't work (html/php)

Tags: php, html, forms

It doesn't send any input when submitting with the button.
As far as I can see, the submit-block (isset...) should be fine. But there's nothing in the variables *name, kuerzel and website*.

Does anybody can help me?

```css
body {
    color: #566787;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    zoom: 105%
}

.table-responsive {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.table-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.table-title {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: #ee8813;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    margin: -20px -25px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.table-title h2 {
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.table-title .btn-group {
    float: right;
}

.table-title .btn {
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: none;
    min-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    outline: none !important;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.table-title .btn i {
    float: left;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.table-title .btn span {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
    border-color: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table.table tr th:first-child {
    width: 60px;
}

table.table tr th:last-child {
    width: 100px;
}

table.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

table.table-striped.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}


table.table td:last-child i {
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

table.table td a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #566787;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none !important;
}

table.table td a:hover {
    color: #2196F3;
}

table.table td a.delete {
    color: #F44336;
    float: right;
}

table.table td i {
    font-size: 19px;
}

table.table .avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.pagination {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}

/* Modal styles */

.modal .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 400px;
}

.modal .modal-header, .modal .modal-body, .modal .modal-footer {
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

.modal .modal-content {
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.modal .modal-footer {
    background: #ecf0f1;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.modal .modal-title {
    display: inline-block;
}

.modal .form-control {
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}

.modal textarea.form-control {
    resize: vertical;
}

.modal .btn {
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.modal form label {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.btn-add {
    background-color: #676767;
}

.btn-add:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

td{
    width: 25%;
}

.credits{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?php print(gethostname()); ?> - Websites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Activate tooltip
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
        // Delete row on delete button click
        $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<!-- Delete Icon -->
<?php $delBtn = "<td><a href='' class='delete' title='Delete' data-toggle='tooltip'><i class='material-icons'>&#xE872;</i></a></td>"; ?>

<!-- Add-Function -->
<?php
$name = $kuerzel = $website = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $websiteList = array(
        array("$name", "$kuerzel", "$website")
    );
    $websiteFileTable = fopen('../textFiles/websites.csv', "a");
    foreach ($websiteList as $fields) {
        fputcsv($websiteFileTable, $fields);
    }
    fclose($websiteFileTable);
    //websites
    $websiteFile = fopen('../textFiles/websites.txt', 'a');
    $websiteContent = "$website\n";
    fwrite($websiteFile, $websiteContent);
    fclose($websiteFile);
    //redirect
    header('Location: test.php');
};
?>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <div class="table-title">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <h2>Raspberry Pi | <b><?php print(gethostname()); ?></b></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href="#addWebsiteModal" class="btn btn-add" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Website hinzufügen</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Vor-/Nachname</th>
                            <th>Kürzel</th>
                            <th>Website</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php
                    $f = fopen("../textFiles/websites.csv", "r");
                    $flag = true; //Skip first line
                    while (($line = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
                        if ($flag) {
                            $flag = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                    ?>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                        }
                        echo "$delBtn";
                        echo "</tr>\n";
                    }
                    fclose($f);
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Modal HTML -->
    <div id="addWebsiteModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form method="POST" action="test.php">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Website hinzufügen</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Vor-/Nachname</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kürzel</label>
                            <input type="text" name="kuerzel" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($kuerzel) ?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Website</label>
                            <input type="url" name="website" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($website) ?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" name="cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="abbrechen">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Hinzufügen">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Don't know what to write further...

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Comment: `Don't know what to write further`...some more detailed results of your debugging would be good. "doesn't send" isn't much of a description. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] - we also don't need a mountain of CSS or irrelevant parts of the HTML, so that would reduce the code-to-text noise ratio a bit.

Comment: Anyway, from reading the code I can see that `$name`, `$kuerzel`, and `$website` are never populated in your code. You set them to empty at the start just before the submit-block and then...nothing. You never attempt to read the data into them from the `$_POST` array. I'd be expecting to see `$name = $_POST["name"];` etc. Have you studied any tutorials on how PHP works with forms?

Comment: Please show the output of `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: @ArRakin why? We can see what the form will submit, and the HTML is all in order. Read my comment above to understand what the real issue is likely to be.

Comment: @ADyson you are right!

Comment: First of all, thanks for the criticism @ADyson. I'll do it better next time!

Comment: I did watch some tutorials and it worked on my first version, which locked a bit different. 
I don't know why I missed the "$name = $_POST["name"];" this time. But it solved my problem. So, thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. Just one more thing - what is the point of `header('Location: test.php');`? You're already on test.php, you don't need to redirect to it. At best this will be producing a warning. You certainly don't need it.

Comment: you're right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyway, from reading the code I can see that $name, $kuerzel, and $website are never populated in your code. You set them to empty at the start just before the submit-block and then...nothing. You never attempt to read the data into them from the $_POST array. I'd be expecting to see $name = $_POST["name"]; etc. Have you studied any tutorials on how PHP works with forms? –

...solved it for me